# How i can remove help_text from a user creation form?

Tags: django

I need to remove help text that appears on my template when I am creating a new user with the **UserCreationForm.**

*I mean this help texts:*

for the username field: `Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.`

and the password confirmation:  `Enter the same password as above, for verification`.

Which comes from `help_text` parameter on field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing help\_text from Django UserCreateForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202845/removing-help-text-from-django-usercreateform)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably rendering your template with something like `{{ form.as_p }}` which renders everything, labels, help_texts, errors and the field itself.

Instead you can do this:

```
{{ form.username.label }}
{{ form.username }}
....
```

Here are more details about manual rendering of forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Answer (score 3):

with  **init** you can set `help_text` None

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['email'].help_text = ''
```

Comment: not a good way to do it. We don't want to override it, but just to hide it

Comment: @MihaiZamfir...what's the difference? It's just being overridden in the form itself, not in the model.

Comment: Actually you can do it like this 
  `class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

      email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
      email.help_text = ''`

Comment: @batiskaf that also nice way .. ! why don't you make answer for that ?. And i am coming from the lon way .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Made an asnwer, Actually you can do it like this

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    email.help_text = ''
```