# Avoid display of help_text in django crispy forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms, django-registration

I am customizing the `RegistrationForm` from `django-registration-redux` with `django-crispy-forms`. For that I have defined a `FormHelper` which is working fine:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        helper = self.helper = FormHelper()
        # Moving field labels into placeholders
        layout = helper.layout = Layout()
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            layout.append(Field(field_name, placeholder=field.label))
        helper.template_pack = 'bootstrap3'
        helper.form_show_labels = False
```

My form is shown as I want: no labels, bootstrap3 and placeholders derived from label.

Now I would also like to suppress the help_text, which is coming from the [`Field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#help-text) definition. There is a somehow related flag [here](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html#bootstrap-helper-attributes) (`help_text_inline`), but that is not intended to disable the display of the help text. I can not find a flag to completely disable the display of the help text in the `FormHelper` [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html). Is this at all possible?

Removing the help text from the `Field` definition is not really an option, since I am inheriting the `RegistrationForm` and I do not want to modify it too much.

Comment: Checkout this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202845/removing-help-text-from-django-usercreateform

Comment: Great, thanks, a pitty I can not accept a comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the trick.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
        self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None
    ...
```

The solution is inspired by this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202845/removing-help-text-from-django-usercreateform).