# Styling error messages with bootstrap

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I'm building my own form to git rid of help text, As I can't change the  builtin form in django to remove the help text.

So far so good, but I can't style the error messages.

It's showing basic ul and il style.

How can I do it ?
Thanks.

```
<form class="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="id_new_password1"> Senha </label><br>
    <div class="">
        <input required text="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" name="new_password1"/>
            {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
    </div><br>
         <label for="id_new_password2"> Confirmar senha </label><br>
    <div class="">

       <input required text="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar senha" name="new_password2"/>
        {{ form.new_password2.errors }}
    </div><br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12" value="Confirmar" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap up error messages in one element.

```
<div class="error-messages">{{ form.new_password1.errors }}</div>

.error-messages {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts). Like this:

```
{% if form.new_password1.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ form.new_password1.errors }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Also, have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202845/removing-help-text-from-django-usercreateform) trying to get rid of the help_text?