# How to edit UserCreationForm password help text?

Tags: django, django-forms

When I create a registration form that inherits from `UserCreationForm`, the text "Your password can't be too similar to your other personal information. Your password must contain at least 8 characters. Your password can't be a commonly used password. Your password can't be entirely numeric."  appears under the password input fields and takes up quite a bit of space. Is there a way I can remove this?

I know the `username` help text can be removed with:

```
 help_texts = {
        'username': None
    }
```

but

```
help_texts = {
        'password1': None,
        'password2': None,
    }
```

does not work.

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing help\_text from Django UserCreateForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202845/removing-help-text-from-django-usercreateform)

Comment: can you please update your question to include your creation template

Answer (score 3):

a bit old but still:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].help_text = None
        self.fields['password2'].help_text = None
```

Those "None" could be edited by whatever text you wish

Comment: +1, This works, thanks! And also, don't hesitate to answer just because some question is old, because a lot of people come from google too...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can remove this? Yes, it is.

1. ! This way will be not recommended ! but it works:

in `settings.py` delete all in the list AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = []

OR

2. My way:
   in .html file I have used this

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <label>{{ form.username.label }}</label>
  {{ form.username }}

  <label>{{ form.password1.label }}</label>
  {{ form.password1 }}

  <label>{{ form.password2.label }}</label>
  {{ form.password2 }}

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  password1 = forms.CharField(
            label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
        password2 = forms.CharField(
            label='Confirm Password(again)', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```